# facebook getLogoutUrl returns a URL with access_token=0, when clicked redirects to Facebook user's home page

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm integrating Facebook with my site and I've added a Logout button whose URL is taken from:

```
$facebook->getLogoutUrl(array('next' => 'http://mydomain.com/logout.php'));
```

The problem is that `logout.php` is never called. Instead, on click of the Logout button, it redirects to the logged-in user's Facebook home page. It doesn't log the user out of Facebook, and it doesn't call my `next` URL.

I noticed that the URL generated by `getLogoutURL()` looks like:

```
https://www.facebook.com/logout.php?next=http://mydomain.com/logout.php&access_token=0
```

Notice there is an **access_token=0**. Should that value not be zero? That's the only thing I can think of that might be causing the problem.

I've already set my FB app's Site URL to `http://mydomain.com`. While testing locally, I've also edited my `hosts` file. I've also googled a lot and I haven't found a solution. The only one that worked was adding an `onclick` to my logout button using `FB.logout()`. But I would need to use PHP.

Any ideas as to why the logout URL is not working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, I've solved this by creating my own logout URL and adding an access token

```
$logoutUrl = 'https://www.facebook.com/logout.php?next=http://mydomain.com/logout.php&access_token=' . $facebook->getAccessToken();
```

Comment: I just ran into this exact same issue, with the access_token being 0 as well. Your fix works for me too, but it feels like a bandaid instead of solving the issue of why the access token is 0. But, I'd put money on that being a FB issue and not something in either of our code bases.

Comment: i couldn't find any documentation regarding this. Is it a hack or original one

Answer (score 4):

I hope you've found a solution! But if not, try with the following code. It worked for me!

```
$facebook->getLogoutUrl(array('next' =>'http://example.com/logout.php', 'access_token'=>$facebook->getAccessToken()));`
```

If you check out the official documentation you'll see it says nothing about setting the access token option in the parameter array but it really works! Good Luck!!

Comment: A little late, but I can't be the only one looking for a solution. This method logs out the user, not just from your site, but from facebook too. It is desirable if you want to screw with users who wish to leave your site :)

Comment: You're right but if you read the api's documentation, Facebook tells that the log out must log you out from Facebook too. I'm agree with you! You should implement a log out that lets the user decide if he/she wants to log out from facebook too.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you need to call getAccessToken BEFORE ask for the logout url.

```
$facebook->getAccessToken();
```

Don't need to call it inside as a getLogoutURL parameter. Just call it one line before:

```
$user = $facebook->getUser();
$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
$logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem too (access_token=0), but then I realized I was clearing Facebook cookies before calling getLogoutURL(). If you get the getLogoutURL() result first, access_token should not be zero.

Answer (score 0):

In v5.0.0 the first parameter of getLogoutUrl() is the access token of the Facebook user's session.

```
public string getLogoutUrl(string $accessToken, string $next, string $separator = '&amp;')
```

Pass it and Facebook will add it to your "next" URL.

[Source](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper/5.0.0)